# Reverse Incremented Column Starting from a Variable

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to essentially create a reverse-incremented column starting from a variable set by a user.

A number will be inserted via an HTML form/PHP into a table. After that I need the following rows to increment down from that number.

I'm open to doing this with SQL or PHP or anything else that might work, I just can't wrap my mind around an effective way to do it.

my table looks like this:

```
RecID---Input
1         7 <--input by user
2         6 <--number drops by 1
3         5
4         4
5         3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From mysql database?

Comment: sql server database

Comment: I would look at using ROW_NUMBER. But not really sure where the values comes from. An [mcve] would make this a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

cannot comment yet.

I don't know exactly what you want but you could use a for loop from the end instead of incrementing the number you decrement it.

```
$value=array();
for($i=_user_input_;$i > 0;$i--){
 $value[]=$i;
}

or 

$value=array('placeholder');
for($i=_user_input_;$i > 0;$i--){
 $value[]=$i;
}
unset($value[0]); // if you want index to start with one
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If data is coming from a mysql database, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Ascending order:

```
SELECT RecID, Input FROM dbname ORDER BY Input ASC
```

Descending order:

```
SELECT RecID, Input FROM dbname ORDER BY Input DESC
```